# android webrtc crash Unable to instantiate codec 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vp8' with err 0xfffffff4

Tags: android, crash, webrtc

im using webrtc for calling, but it's crash in China rom device mostly but also some others(even samsung). here is the crash log:

```
2021-09-12 18:29:31.899 1218-14625/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Omx_vdec::Comp Init Returning failure, errno 12
2021-09-12 18:29:31.899 1218-14625/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: eventfd_write failed for fd: -1, errno = 9, force stop async_thread
2021-09-12 18:29:31.899 1218-14625/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Invalid input: -1
2021-09-12 18:29:31.913 1218-14625/? E/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service: Failed to allocate omx component 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vp8'  err=InsufficientResources(0x80001000)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.916 3298-27657/com.civix.link E/ACodec: Unable to instantiate codec 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vp8' with err 0xfffffff4.
2021-09-12 18:29:31.916 3298-27657/com.civix.link E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0xfffffff4, internalError -12)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.918 3298-27656/com.civix.link E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xfffffff4, actionCode 0, while in state 1
2021-09-12 18:29:31.924 1195-32507/? E/ResourceManagerService: getLowestPriorityBiggestClient_l: lowest priority 0 vs caller priority 0
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/MediaCodec-JNI: try to release MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec()...
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/MediaCodec-JNI: done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vp8, error 0xfffffff4
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1912)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1890)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoDecoder.initDecodeInternal(HardwareVideoDecoder.java:173)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoDecoder.initDecode(HardwareVideoDecoder.java:150)
2021-09-12 18:29:31.925 3298-25911/com.civix.link E/rtc: #
    # Fatal error in: gen/sdk/android/generated_base_jni/jni/../../../../../../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.h, line 37
    # last system error: 0
    # Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
    #
```

I have some device work normally, but in some device(even Samsung) it crash after 1 minute -> 30 minutes running call.

About my webrtc, im using default all:

```
peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                    .setOptions(options)
                    .setVideoEncoderFactory(new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(MeetingClient.mRootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true))
                    .setVideoDecoderFactory(new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(MeetingClient.mRootEglBase.getEglBaseContext()))
                    .createPeerConnectionFactory();
```

Can someone tech me how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: i still got problem with Android, IOS work nomally, my solution is only implement 1 subscribe to view and disable all to avoid crash